# Configurable Product Price not displaying

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, price, associate-products

I have created configurable product with associated simple products.

**In that, I want a product A with size unit 100g , price 150 and special price 140 and Product B with size unit 50g , price 80 and special price 75. How I will do this?**

I have given price and special price for the simple product.. 
But it is not displaying the price..

Answer (score 0):

By default magento does not provide that functionality if you want achieve this then you have two option

1) increase and decrease price in associate product tab for that product option

2) install this extension https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-configurable-products.html

you need to do some modification for this extension after that you can use.

Comment: so we can't give special price for associate products by default..

Comment: If You want to achieve that then install this extension. By default magento show config. product price not associated product price